# Dynamic Fields in Wizard (TransientModel)

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I'm using Odoo 16. I have a task to develop a wizard where I have to show dynamic fields, meaning I have a `template_ids` field, which is `Many2one` field, and in the `template_ids` model, there is another `One2many` field `variables_id`.

In the wizard, when I select `template_ids`, then I have to check how many `variables_id`s are available. If there are 3 variables, then I have to show 3 fields in the wizard.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: do you mean like, the dynamic creation of field on the wizard's form, by onchange with some conditions?

Comment: @farisfath25 Yes